# Перенос строки в PHP в 'echo'

Tags: html, php

Есть код PHP:

> `<?php
> $vvv = '<select>!!!<option>1</option>!!!<option>2</option>!!!</select>';
> echo $vvv;
> ?>`

Как в том месте, где стоит '!!!' сделать так, чтобы был перенос строки в исходном коде, т.е. чтобы было не так:

> `<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>`

А вот так должно быть:

> `<select>
> <option>1</option>
> <option>2</option>
> </select>`

Comment: \n (\r\n на windows).
Сработает только в двойных кавычках.
Также естьб константа PHP_EOL, в которой лежит последовательность символов для перевода строки в текущей ОС.

Comment: Блин, я же уже обещал себе, что буду писать такое ответами.

Comment: @Etki, важнее смысл ответа или статус ответа?

Comment: @TheDoctor, важнее, что иногда меня замыкает, и у меня начинается бугурт, когда мой комментарий не замечают или отвечают так же.

Comment: @Etki, угу, я тоже это заметил.  
У ответа есть преобразователь в комментарий (вроде как был), а обратное никто не предлагал сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если говорить про исходный код, то можно еще воспользоваться `\n`

Таким образом строка в исходном коде будет с переносом.

Единственное условие, которое нужно учесть: `\n` должно быть в двойных кавычках, иначе все это дело будет экранироваться.

```
$var = "<div>\n</div>";
echo $var;
```

Результат в исходном коде:

```
<div>
</div>
```

---

Также можешь воспользоваться константой `PHP_EOL`, которая как раз и отвечает за перенос строк. В последнее время я этой константой и пользуюсь.

```
$var = "<div>".PHP_EOL."</div>";
echo $var;
```

Результат в исходном коде:

```
<div>
</div>
```

P.S. Перенос будет отображаться **только** в исходном коде. В браузере, если не пользоваться специальными тегами, перенос будет заменен на пробел.

Answer (score 1):

Просто взять и перенести на новую строку. В чем именно проблема? Ну если я правильно понял.

Ну или `<br />`.

Comment: Ой, точно. Что-то туплю я сегодня. Забыл ведь, что существует такой волшебный тег, как '<br />' :D

Comment: Просто в Javascript используют '/m' или '&#13'. Вот я и запутался. Просто когда написал эти символы, браузер их мне на экран просто вывел и всё.

Answer (score 1):

Все элементарно просто, используй `<br>`

```
<?php 
$vvv = '<select><br><option>1</option><br><option>2</option><br></select>'; 
echo $vvv; 
?>
```